# Using Firebase Realtime Database `update` to perform multiple updates on the same node

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm working with Firebase Realtime Database and I want to update multiple properties under the same node using the `update()` method. I've seen examples of using `update()` to perform multiple updates on different nodes, but I want to clarify if it's valid to use `update()` on the same node. Here's an example of what I have in mind:

```js
const rootRef = ref.child('');
rootRef.update({
  'users/gracehop/city': 'New York',
  'users/gracehop/nickname': 'Amazing Grace',
  'users/anotherUser/nickname': 'John Doe',
  'customers/someId/role/admin': true,
  'customers/IdForUserThatShouldBeDeleted': null,
});
```

In this example, I'm updating properties under the "users" node, specifically under the "gracehop" user. Is this a valid use of the update method, and will it work as intended?

Documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data#section-update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this a valid use of the update method, and will it work as intended?

Yes, that's the way to go ahead with updating multi-path locations in the Realtime Database. Please also note that if you perform such an operation, either all updates are performed or none of them are applied, if the operation fails.

Comment: Thank you for providing your response and the accompanying note. I believed before that it would handle events up to failure as if executing `Promise.all()`.

Comment: You're very welcome, JW.